# How to properly store List<T> object items to another instance of List<T> without affecting its individual item values - C#

Tags: c#, list, class

Here is the problem:

I have this class `Person` :

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I initialized this object named `workersA` as the source object:

```
List<Person> workersA = new List<Person>()
{
   new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Emp1", Age = 27  },
   new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Emp2", Age = 18  },
   new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Emp3", Age = 23  },
};
```

I declare the other two instances as this:

```
List<Person> workersB = new List<Person>();
List<Person> workersC = new List<Person>();
```

And fill it with different approach:

On `workersB` stored from source using `.ToList()` extension.

```
workersB = workersA.ToList();
```

And on `workersC` stored from source using `foreach` statement.

```
foreach (var w in workersA.ToList())
{
    workersC.Add(w);
}
```

---

Now when i try to modify the `Age` property of the source object.. here's the code:

```
foreach (var p in workersA.ToList())
{
    p.Age--;
}
```

And output all the result using this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Wokers A:");
foreach (var p in workersA.ToList())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} Name: {1}, Age: {2}", p.Id, p.Name, p.Age);
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Wokers B:");
foreach (var p in workersB.ToList())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} Name: {1}, Age: {2}", p.Id, p.Name, p.Age);
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Wokers B:");
foreach (var p in workersB.ToList())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} Name: {1}, Age: {2}", p.Id, p.Name, p.Age);
}
```

Here is what ive'd got:

```
Wokers A:
Id: 1 Name: Emp1, Age: 26
Id: 2 Name: Emp2, Age: 17
Id: 3 Name: Emp3, Age: 22

Wokers B:
Id: 1 Name: Emp1, Age: 26   // 27 - expectation
Id: 2 Name: Emp2, Age: 17   // 18 - expectation
Id: 3 Name: Emp3, Age: 22   // 22 - expectation

Wokers C:
Id: 1 Name: Emp1, Age: 26   //  27 - expectation
Id: 2 Name: Emp2, Age: 17   //  18 - expectation
Id: 3 Name: Emp3, Age: 22   //  22 - expectation
```

To address the question clearly

> Why did i get the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, ultimately, every element in both the `workersB` and `workersC` will still point to individual `Person` instance you originally created. Thus they all refer to the same instances - thus you got identical results.

In short, you got three *different* lists having the three *same* `Person` instances

When you do this:

```
workersB = workersA.ToList();
```

You create a new instance of `List`, *not* the new instances of individual object in the List. Likewise, when you do this:

```
foreach (var w in workersA.ToList())
{
    workersC.Add(w);
}
```

You are passing the same `Person` reference in `workersA` to `workersC`. *but* they are all referring to the same `Person` instances.

And so when you  finally do:

```
foreach (var p in workersA.ToList())
{
    p.Age--;
}
```

Every `Person` instance's `Age` is changed, though there are three different lists which contain them.

---

**Solution:**

If you really want to pass different `Person` to the three lists, one way is by implementing a `Clone` method for the `Person` (which you would find in `IClonable` interface):

```
public Person Clone(){
    return new Person() { Id = this.Id, Name = this.Name, Age = this.Age };
}
```

Then you input the other lists with the `Clone` rather than with the original `Person`:

```
foreach (var w in workersA.ToList())
{
    workersC.Add(w.Clone()); //use Clone here
}
```

---

**Edit 2, OP's final solution according to the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109641/discussion-between-shift-n-tab-and-ian)**

```
class Person : ICloneable 
{     
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Position { get; set; } 
    public int Age { get; set; } 
    
    public Person Clone() 
    { 
        return (Person)this.MemberwiseClone(); 
    } 
     
    object ICloneable.Clone() 
    { 
        return this.Clone(); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab ah yes, you should create a copy/clone of the three `Person`s rather than making three lists containing the same `Person`. One simple way is by making the `Person` having `Clone` method to create new `Person` everytime based on its own properties, and then you pass the cloned `Person` instead of the original `Person`

Comment: ill test this one, but `IClonable` interface could not be found

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab yep, you could make your `Person` inherit from `IClonable` to force the `Clonable` behavior if you wish. ;)

Comment: but `IClonable` interface could not be found, is there any assembly needed sir?

Comment: Sorry, I misspell it, it should be `ICloneable` (with `e`). It is in the `System`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109641/discussion-between-shift-n-tab-and-ian).

Comment: I will approved this one but prior to the correct implementation here it is based on your answer

`class Person : ICloneable 
{ 
public int Id { get; set; } 
public string Name { get; set; } 
public string Position { get; set; } 
public int Age { get; set; } 

public Person Clone() 
{ 
return (Person)this.MemberwiseClone(); 
} 
} 
object ICloneable.Clone() 
{ 
return this.Clone(); 
} 
}`

Answer (score 2):

You get the same output because your `Person` class is a reference type. So, each of the three lists contain references to the same objects. Thus, if you change one, you change also the corresponding elements in the other two lists, because they point to the same element. If you want the `workersB` and `workersC` to contain independent elements, you have to copy them. For instance add a copy constructor

```
class Person {
   ....

   public Person(Person other) {
       this.Id = other.Id;
       this.Name = other.Name;
       ...
   }
}
```

and when adding the elements to `workersB` and `workersC` call that copy constructor.

```
 foreach (Person p in workersA) {
     workersB.Add(new Person(p));
     workersC.Add(new Person(p));
 }
```

or as an alternative

```
 workersB = workersA.Select(x=> new Person(x)).ToList();
 workersC = workersA.Select(x=> new Person(x)).ToList();
```

This way, all the elements are new objects and not related to each other.

Comment: does this one has a better performance than using ICloneable?

Comment: I did not look into performance. Just for the principle how to do it. But it may depend on how you implement `ICloneable.Clone()`. For best performance you may have a look at @Nikolai's anwer

Answer (score 2):

In order to isolate the results you need to create separate instances. One of the ways to achieve is to clone your instances while creating new lists.

Take a look at this answer it covers the area quite comprehensively:

[Fastest Way to do Shallow Copy in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966451/fastest-way-to-do-shallow-copy-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

as class Person is reference type (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) your lists contain only the references to the instances of Person you created initially. When you change the instance in any list, the instance is changed in every list.